# Deux façons pour exprimer l'inverse de « il faut »

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, constructions, phrase

En pensant à quelque chose d'aléatoire aujourd'hui, je me suis rendu compte que je ne sais pas comment  traduire correctement l'inverse d'une construction avec « il faut ». Par exemple, si je dit à quelqu'un

> Il faut que tu y ailles.

j'imagine qu'il y a deux façons de laquelle il peut me répondre pour formuler le contraire. S'il n'est pas d'accord, il peut dire tout simplement

> Non, il ne faut pas que j'y aille.

et en anglais, je crois que ça veut dire

> No, I don't need to go [there]

Mais par exemple, s'il veut dire « non, je *ne devrais pas aller* », au début - c'est à dire qu'il ne veut pas exprimer le fait que ce n'est pas nécessaire qu'il y aille, en d'autres termes, qu'il n'est pas d'accord, mais au contraire, que lui-même pense que ce n'est pas une bonne idée d'y aller.

Je suis désolé si c'est un petit peu déroutant, mais j'ai du mal à exprimer ce que je veux dire en français quand il s'agit de ça pour exactement cette raison. Je suppose que je peux le redire comme suit: comment distinguer entre « Je ne devrais pas [faire qch] » et « Non, je ne suis pas d'accord que c'est quelque chose qu'il faut que je fasse » ? En anglais, je le poserais comme suit:

**How can I express the two different ideas of "I should not do something" and "No, it's not necessary that I do something"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« ***Il faut que tu y ailles*** » peut avoir au moins deux sens suivant le contexte.

Le premier est « ***il est temps maintenant pour toi de partir*** » et le second recouvre plusieurs nuances : « ***il est nécessaire/utile/convenable qui tu ailles à cet endroit***. »

La réponse « ***non, il ne faut pas que j'y aille*** » est possible, mais probablement pas la plus courante. Si l'interlocuteur n'est pas d'accord, il pourra plutôt répondre, dans le premier cas :

> Non, je reste.

> Non, je préfère rester ici.

> Non, je reste encore un peu.

etc.

et dans le deuxième cas, la raison du refus sera souvent clairement exprimée :

> Non, faut pas ! (signifie souvent: c'est interdit)

> Non, j'ai pas besoin d'y aller (c'est pas nécessaire/utile/convenable/obligé... ).

> Non, c'est pas le moment.

> Non, c'est pas une bonne idée.

> Non, pas seul(e).

> Non, je préfère que tu y ailles toi.

etc.

Comme toujours, le contexte du dialogue pourra limiter les interprétations et choix possibles de ce dialogue.

Comment: Merci - c'est très clair comme toujours. En gros, on n'utilise pas la négation de « il faut » mais plutôt d'autre phrases pour exprimer ce que on veut dire précisément.

Answer (score -1):

Il n'y a pas de mot qui permette de marquer clairement la différence que vous cherchez ; dans les deux cas la personne n'est pas d'accord sur le plan d'une obligation qui est suggérée. Dans le premier c'est une question de système et cette personne n'a aucune récrimination contre le système et veut seulement avertir qu'elle n'est pas concernée par ce système, qu'elle n'est pas en faute (plus ou moins, ce pourrait ne pas être vraiment une faute) du moins selon ce que le système prévoit. Dans le second cas elle n'est pas d'accord parce qu'elle juge que le système est en faute et prévoit qu'elle devrait faire quelque chose alors qu'elle se rend compte que le système ne la traite pas justement.

Pour le premier cas le verbe « devoir » convient mais utilisé au présent, et « avoir » convient aussi.

- Non, je ne **dois** pas [faire qqc]. -- Non, je n'**ai**  pas  à [faire qqc].

Il peut convenir aussi pour le second cas si utilisé au conditionnel présent mais c'est peu explicite, ambigu, et cette personne doit alors continuer à donner des précisions pour que l'on sache de quoi il s'agit. De la même manière on peut utiliser " **avoir** ».

- Non je ne **devrais**  pas [faire qqc]. (*forte probabilité ou désaccord sur une question de norme*)
- Non, je n'**ai** pas à [faire qqc]. (*indicatif présent seulement*)

Dans le second cas il faut toujours donner des précisions, rentrer dans le vif du sujet si l'interlocuteur ne sait pas déjà de quoi il s'agit, et cela même si l'on commence par « Non, je ne suis pas d'accord. », qui bien que prémoniteur d'un problème de fond (système en erreur) n'est toujours pas assez spécifique pour rendre la raison du désaccord claire.

Comment: Est-ce que la personne qui a bas voté peut expliquer pour quoi? Parce que pour moi, cette réponse-là a l'air logique.

Comment: Peut-être à cause du vocabulaire du premier paragraphe. *Il n'y a pas de **mot***, pourquoi *mot* ? Ce qui est recherché, c'est une façon de répondre, pas un mot particulier, et aussi la répétition excessive du mot ***système*** par la suite, mot dont on ne comprend pas la présence ici. *Une récrimination contre le système*, ça veut généralement dire *I have a grievance against the political/social system*.